# sync.Waitgroup doesn't block the execution

Tags: go

Consider this code snippet

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    nap := func() {
        wg.Add(1)
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println("nap done")
        wg.Done()
    }

    go nap()
    go nap()
    go nap()

    fmt.Println("nap time")
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("all done")
}
```

Running such code gives expected output:

```
nap time
nap done
nap done
nap done
all done
```

Now let's ommit first standard output print before `wg.Wait()`:

```
// fmt.Println("nap time")
wg.Wait()
fmt.Println("all done")
```

The output now changes to unexpected:

```
all done
```

Where expected would be:

```
nap done
nap done
nap done
all done
```

Same code on the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8aNcWMwhs6E) does give this output without a need of omitting the stdout print.

Can you explain to me, what I am missing there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though this looks like magic, it has a logical explanation. Go doesn't guarantee the order of goroutines execution. There are three goroutines spawned in given snippet code, but in fact, there are four of them: the very first one that is spawned when the execution starts.

#### Stdout print is omitted

This goroutine spawned three nap functions and continued in its plan. It was so fast that it executed `wg.Wait()` before any of spawned goroutines was able to call `wg.Add(1)`. As a result `wg.Wait()` didn't block the execution and program ended.

#### Print to stdout before `wg.Wait()`

In this case, program execution was different, goroutines were able to make  `wg.Add(1)` call because the main goroutine wasn't fast as in the first case. This behavior isn't guaranteed, which can be seen in the linked playground example.

#### It has nothing to do with stdout print

The following code sample will give the same expected output:

```
time.Sleep(time.Second)
wg.Wait()
fmt.Println("all done")
```

The `fmt.Println()` had the same impact as `time.Sleep()` had.

#### Idiomatic way

The rule is simple: call `wg.Add(1)` before spawning the goroutine.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    nap := func() {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println("nap done")
        wg.Done()
    }

    napCount := 3
    wg.Add(napCount)
    for i := 0; i < napCount; i++ {
        go nap()
    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("all done")
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer but it could be made even better by explaining how OP would correctly wait for goroutines to finish without the calling goroutine exiting (as well as the idiomatic way to handle data sharing in Go)

Comment: While this is good info, I don't see the actual answer anywhere, which is to always call `wg.Add` before dispatching the goroutine.

Comment: Yeah if he calls Add *before* starting the goroutine, that would fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments, I've updated the answer.